# ASP.Net Core | Issue with Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, navigation

I'm new to ASP.net core and I was trying to write a redirect action using @Html.ActionLink

Here is my code :

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("PRIVACY PAGE", "Privacy", "Privacy")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This action link is supposed to redirect to the PrivacyPage, but instead, the values that I pass are being sent as a parameter to the URL

> https://localhost:7020/?action=Privacy&controller=Privacy

[image: s]

The expected result is

> https://localhost:7020/Privacy

[image]

Not sure what I'm missing. Will this ActionLink work only for the MVC projects?

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, I think you put wrong controller name.

```
@Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionname", "controllername")
```

Instead of `@Html.ActionLink("PRIVACY PAGE", "Privacy", "Privacy")` it will be `@Html.ActionLink("PRIVACY PAGE", "Privacy", "Home")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `asp-page` attribute with Razor Pages.

```
<a asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
```

if your Privacy page in another folder like */Pages/Home/Privacy*

```
<a asp-page="/Home/Privacy">Privacy</a>
```

For more documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0